# The function is not called within another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, telegram

I've encountered a completely incomprehensible behavior of calling a function inside a function.
When I call telegram() function inside runParser() after fs.writeFile it just doesn't work. But if I execute it outside runParser() function, it works properly. That said, I have a log() function that gives me a console.log with text. It works. Why is this happening, can I call it inside the function? Also, I noticed that if I put the function at the beginning of try block it works.

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = 'https://rezka.ag/films/page/';
const watched = '/?filter=watching';
const telegram = require('./telegram.js')
const {Bot} = require("tgapi");
const log=require('./log')

////дата
let today = new Date();
let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = mm + dd + yyyy;
////
let runParser = async () => {
    let flag = true
    let itog = []
    let counter = 1
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        slowMo: 100,
        devtools: true
    })
    try {
        let page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setViewport({width: 1400, height: 900})
        while (flag) {
            await page.goto(`${url}${counter}${watched}`)
            await page.waitForSelector('div.b-footer__right')
            let html = await page.evaluate(async () => {
                let page = []
                try {
                    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.b-content__inline_item')
                    divs.forEach(div => {
                        let a = div.querySelector('#main > div.b-container.b-content.b-wrapper > div.b-content__inline > div > div.b-content__inline_items > div > div.b-content__inline_item-link > a')
                        let obj = {
                            link: a.href,
                            title: a.innerText,
                            info: div.querySelector('#main > div.b-container.b-content.b-wrapper > div.b-content__inline > div > div.b-content__inline_items > div> div.b-content__inline_item-link > div').innerText
                        }
                        page.push(obj)
                    })

                } catch (e) {

                    console.log(e)
                }
                return page

            }, {waitUntil: 'div.b-footer__right'})
            itog.push(html)
            console.log(itog)
            for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (counter === 5) {
                    flag = false
                }
            }
            counter++

        }
        await browser.close()
        fs.writeFile(`movie ${today}.json`, JSON.stringify({data: itog}), err => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('saved')
        })
telegram(today)

        log()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        await browser.close()
    }
    return  JSON.stringify(itog)
}


module.exports = runParser
```

**telegram.js**

```
const {Bot} = require("tgapi");
const fs = require("fs");

const telegram =  function  (today) {
    const bot = new Bot('TOKEN')
    const chat_id = 123456
    const document = fs.createReadStream(`movie ${today}.json`)
    bot
        .sendDocument({chat_id, document})
        .then(console.log)

}

module.exports = telegram
```

**log.js**

```
  function log(){
    console.log("work well")
}
module.exports=log
```

Comment: What's the output of telegram(today) inside the function.

Comment: It appears that you are not handling the async code in telegram properly. Bot.sendDocument is async so you need to await it or return the promise. Then in your calling code, you need to await for the promise to resolve when you call telegram(...).

Comment: @kevintechie They're using `.then()` after `sendDocument`.

Comment: @diesan-romero not quite understand what you mean by output. The function sends the file to telegram, but it does not work inside the runParser function.

Comment: Output mean result of the function execution.

Comment: @Barmar Just because they use then doesn't mean that they don't have to await the resolution of the promise. If the calling function completes before the promise completes, you won't have the results you expect.

Comment: One possibility is that `while (flag) {...some code}` is an infinite loop and does not work.  That is generally NOT something you do in Javascript because it's not compatible with the event loop unless there's an `await` inside the loop.  Without a properly coded `await`, the while loop is waiting on a flag to change, but the flag can't change until the `while` loop stops looping and lets the event loop run.

Comment: Without the minimal reproducible code, we're all taking (educated) guesses here. In my experience, if the only thing that changes is the location of the function, execution order is a factor and that's usually due to async issues.

Comment: Also, it's not clear where `today` gets set, so maybe telegram() is executing with an undefined `today` because it's not being awaited. Try putting in a console.log('Start telegram') to debug.

Comment: @kevintechie 
Thanks for your responses. I've edited the code so you can see it in its entirety. The whole script except telegram(today) after fs.writeFile works correctly. It gives me what I expect and it doesn't hang or go into an infinite loop anywhere. I checked the return at the end of my code, it works as I need it to. The only problem is the telegram function.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently your `telegram` function contains some asynchronous code. At least that's what I'm guessing based on the `then` callback after calling `sendDocument`

If that's correct, you should return the promise and use an `await` in front of the `telegram` call.

Also, you use `fs.writeFile` which is asynchronous but does not return a promise (it uses a callback parameter). Since you use the file's content inside the `telegram` function, I would recommend using `fs.promises.writeFile` instead and await its completion.

**inside function runParser**

```
await browser.close()
await fs.promises.writeFile(`movie ${today}.json`, JSON.stringify({data: itog}))
console.log('saved')
await telegram(today)
log()
```

**telgram.js**

```
const {Bot} = require("tgapi");
const fs = require("fs");

const telegram =  function  (today) {
  const bot = new Bot('TOKEN')
  const chat_id = 123456
  const document = fs.createReadStream(`movie ${today}.json`)
  return bot
    .sendDocument({chat_id, document})
    .then(console.log)
}

module.exports = telegram
```

More generally, when moving some code around results in OK/KO situations, it very often means that there are some asynchronous issues somewhere.

Comment: This won't help unless `telegram` also returns the promise or is defined with `async`.

Comment: If a javascript function contains some asynchronous code (a call to an asynchronous function for example), it becomes itself asynchronous. Since `bot.sendDocument` is followed by a `then` callback, I'm guessing that this is a function that returns a promise. If your `log` function reacts to the result of the `telegram` function, indicating whether or not it ran successfully, it needs to run after the completion of the `telegram` function, thus the need for the `await` keyword.

Comment: It runs asynchronously, but it doesn't return a promise that you can `await` unless it actually returns the promise or is declared with `async`. It could use `return bot.sendDocument...`

Comment: if a function doesn't return any value, it still returns `void` and if it contains asynchronous code, it will return `Promise<void>`. What happens here is that it executes `bot.sendDocument`, doesn't wait for its completion and then executes your `log` function. Did you try using `await`?

Comment: That's simply not true. Calling asynchronous code internal to the function does not make it return a promise automatically. You have to either declare it `async` or return it explicitly.

Comment: @Ben if I use await before calling telegram, the function doesn't work, I don't see anything in console.log that returns .then. The log() function after the telegram() function works correctly and returns information to me in the console.  If I add async before the original function in telegram.js file, and also add await before bot, everything hangs after fs.writeFile, log() does not work. Return before await gives the same result.

Comment: @Barmar, my apologies, you are correct indeed, the automatic promise wrapping only happens when the function is declared as async. 
@blackenergy1645, thanks for updating your code, you have another problem here because `fs.writeFile` is also asynchronous and you are expecting the file to be written when reading it from your `telegram` function. I would recommend using `fs.promises.writeFile` and await its result. Then I would return `bot.sendDocument` (which is most probably a `Promise<value>`) from your `telegram` function and `await` it. I'll wait for your feedback before updating my answer

Comment: @Ben if I understood you correctly, then doing fs.promises.writeFile I should add .then and call telegram there ? That didn't work for me. I also tried just calling the function, without .then. I did return. Did everything as you described but still didn't get a working scheme.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will clarify everything